# JQuery and Bootstrap: How to add image from a list of images to a carousel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to JQuery and I'm making a make-your-own carousel where there is a selection of pictures and you want to add pictures to the carousel on click.

There are pictures on the left side of the page to choose from, and the carousel is on the right side. The code for the list of images goes something like this.

```
<div class="pics">
  <div class="col-sm-4 iu">
    <img src="img/iu.png" alt="IU" class="img-thumbnail" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-4 hyuna">
    <img src="img/hyuna.png" alt="hyuna" class="img-thumbnail" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
  </div>
```

The code for the carousel slides is this

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <div class="item active">
    <img src="img/minah.png" alt="minah" />
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h1>This is Minah.</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <img src="img/juwoo.png" alt="juwoo" />
  <div class="carousel-caption">
     <h1>This is Juwoo.</h1>
  </div>
```

The page starts off with a default carousel already in place and it's supposed to become completely empty when an image from the list is clicked.

Comment: Does the default carousel show all the images? Also, "it's supposed to become completely empty when an image from the list is clicked." does this mean the carousel becomes empty when an image is clicked or just the image clicked is shown?

Comment: The default carousel only shows some images. And when an image is clicked, the default carousel goes away and the clicked image goes on the carousel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give an idea, I think it will go something like this:

```
// As the document loads, keep a variable to define that you have not clicked a image.
var image_clicked = false;
$(document).on("click",".img-thumbnail",function(e){
  // Once you click a image on the side.
  var $this = $(e.target)
  // Check the variable
  if(!image_clicked){
    // If not clicked, clear the carousel
    $(".carousel-inner").html("");
    // mark it as clicked, so that the second time you click a image, it wont come to this block.
    image_clicked = true;
  }
    // It will append the new image to the carousel.
    // On the second time you click a image, you will only be appending elements to the carousel.
    // Add item div to the carousel.
    $(".carousel-inner").append("<div class='item'><div class='carousel-caption'><h1></h1></div></div>");
    // Get the added items
    var item = $(".carousel-inner").find(".item");
    // Get the current item and prepend a image to it.
    $(item[item.length-1]).prepend($this);
    // Remove the previous active class that was assigned
    $(".carousel-inner item").each(function(i,it){
      if($(it).hasClass("active")){
        $(it).removeClass("active");
      }
    });
    // Add a active class to the current added item
    $(item[item.length-1]).addClass("active");
    // If you images on the side have a value attribute to them
    // then keep it as caption
    $(item[item.length-1]).find(".carousel-caption h1").html($this.attr("value"));
});
```

I havent tested this, but it should be something similar to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hey, thanks. It kind of works. Can you tell me what is happening in the code?

Comment: Ok updated the answer with comments... Hope it helps.